# Possibility to make website analytics public?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

let's say I wanted to make a google analytics report public (for example to include it through in `iframe` in an existing website) -- is there any way to do this?

`ga` would be my first choice, but I would also consider any other analytics solution that allows viewing the data, without having to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data studio looks good, but I ended up going with matomo in the end.

see https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_20130/ and https://matomo.org/docs/embed-matomo-reports/ for embedding a dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

You could create public reports within Data Studio using the GA Data and then embed these into a website.

More information on embedding DS Reports here:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en